# I'm going to wait on you

Tags: phrases

### (wait on someone)

**Boy**: Is it ready yet?

**Mom**: Not quite. Another few seconds.

**Boy**: I’ll get it.

**Mom**: No, it's not the doorbell, Jack. It's the bell of the microwave. It means our supper is ready.

**Boy**: Supper! you said we were going to have dinner.

**Mom**: Oh, supper means dinner. It's the same thing really. Now, you'll be the customer and I'll be the waiter. Please sit down, sir.

**Boy**: OK. Oh, thank you. Now, you're going to, how do you say it, **Wait on me**?

**Mom**: Yes, I'm going to **wait on you**. I'm going to serve you, and first of all, I'm going to serve you some soup.

---

What does "**wait on you**" mean in this dialogue?

"Serve food or drink to you"   **or**   "be a servant for you"?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

“Wait on you” would mean that the waiter/waitress performs their job as a waiter/waitress to the customer.

For example, taking orders and bringing food/drinks to the customers table.

Basically it is the waiter/waitress providing a service to the customer.

Comment: Thank you, Dan Khan

Comment: You’re welcome.